# How to reverse such codes in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm going through a source code of a website done in PHP. However, all pages are seems to have similar format which contains neither readable PHP nor html codes, of course inside PHP tags. How I reverse and understand how this is translated to Html for browsers?

```
    $_F=__FILE__;$_X='P2kNVg1WDVYJCQkJCUI5c2M+czlT1ZV2k=';
    $_D=strrev('edoced_46esab');
    eval($_D('JF9YPWJhc2+VlhvIEh9NkdD0wOw='));
```

Comment: I have a feeling you have been hacked

Comment: That code reverses itself, but beware do not run it all

Comment: Can you share a link for tutorial of understanding of such concepts @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worries! Meet php-unobfuscate, a simple tool for reversing lame PHP obfuscators.

Supports the following methods:

```
usage of $_D=strrev('edoced_46esab')
```

To run, just use:

```
php -f unobfuscate.php obfuscated-php-file.php
```

For more detail, check [this url](https://github.com/mgcm/php-unobfuscate)